# Is there a way to raise the max cities for a corporation?

Tags: civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

I am currently playing Beyond the Sword.

I can still build executives after the 5 limit, but my executives can't found new corporations.

Comment: There are no max cities, the five refers to the number of execs you can have at the same time. Are you sure the cities you are sending them to don't already have the corp? Also execs don't found new corparations, they spread existing ones to more cities

Comment: This changes everything. No, they definitely didn't have the corp. But I guess this just means experiment time. Thx. If you submit this as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executives work like missionaries. The five refers to the number of executives you can have at the same time.

when you send them to a city, they spread their corporation to that city, giving the city the effects of the corp and the founder of the corp a gold bonus. This costs a lump sum of gold, which is increased if the city already has another corp in it. So, this may be one cause of your problem, you don't have the gold to spread the corp.

Execs are unable to expand their corp in a city if the city already has that corporation or if it the headquarter of a competing (=uses the same resources) corp (denoted by the star next to the corp icon).

Also, if a civ uses the state property (affects all corps) or mercantilism (affects only foreign corps) civic corporations are severly hindered, I can't remember whether the corp cannot spread in the cities at all or if those civics prevent the effects of the corp.

Corporations can only be founded by a great person.